# The call is ambiguous: FindWindow(String, String);

Tags: c#, findwindow, setparent

I am using this code:

```
IntPtr hwndf = this.Handle;
IntPtr hwndParent = FindWindow("ProgMan.exe", null);
SetParent(hwndf, hwndParent);
```

However I get an error. The error says :

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'HyperBox.Form1.FindWindow(string, string)' and
>   'HyperBox.Form1.FindWindow(string, string)'

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have 2 FindWindow methods?  Those two look identical.  Is your project configuration OK?

Comment: Ah yes I had two separate methods that were different. Thanks alot.

Answer (score -1):

Cast null to string so that the program knows which of the overridden methods to use:

```
IntPtr hwndf = this.Handle;
IntPtr hwndParent = FindWindow("ProgMan.exe", (string)null);
SetParent(hwndf, hwndParent);
```

Comment: Both methods accept two string parameters. Casting null to a string will still be ambiguous.

Comment: Ahh ok - if you have two methods with the same signature (i.e. same name & parameter types) that's the issue; the compiler has no way of differentiating so will reject it.  A simple (hack) fix would be to change one of the parameters on one of the inputs to accept a character array or object instead of a string, then cast back to a string when you come to use it in the code.